# Only one pin on same gps location (kml/google earth)?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

Hy,

I am developing some sort of monitoring system with GPS coordinates through KML in Google Earth. It happens a lot, that two or more pins are located in exactly the same GPS location (because of to small difference GPS to detect).

Is there any way to limit that only one pin is displayed on that location so I won't get that flower effect on click?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. If you want to prevent it you should not create placemarks for locations that you already created one for. The extra advantage in that case is that you can group any names/descriptions or whatever and add that as one name/description to your one placemark. That way if the user clicks the placemark and the info pops up it will inform the user of all the devices that are there.

In my case I added some logic that if more than 10 devices were at the same point I would not show all the individual names anymore (too long list that won't scroll) and added a [a nn user more] type of message.